# Bootstrap 'collapse in' class not appending issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing an issue with Bootstrap Collapse option when I click on some item I need to open some stars directive (uib-rating)for which I have used UI-Bootstrap

**HTML:**

```
<p class="text-align" style="cursor:pointer"><a ng-click="fnDisplayQuestions(value.quesList.quesListName,$index)" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{#value.quesList.quesListName}}" >{{value.quesList.quesListName}}</a></p>
<uib-rating ng-model="rate" id="{{value.quesList.quesListName}}" class="collapse" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="rating=value" ng-click="fnPutRating(rating)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating>
```

These both are in **ng-repeat** and here **value.quesList.quesListName** comes from **ng-repeat** itself.

**JS-CODE:**

```
$scope.fnDisplayQuestions = function(qListName, index) { 

        $scope.indexQList = index;
        $scope.sQList = qListName;

        if (parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('currentRound')) == 1) {
            getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQuestions(qListName).then(function(response) {
                $scope.aQuestions = response;
            });
        } else {
            getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQuesRoundBased(qListName).then(function(response) {
                $scope.aQuestions = response;
            });
        }

}
```

I don't know why this collapse is not working properly.

Comment: Always use the second parameter of `parseInt`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `ng-if` and some condition as below:

HTML:

```
<p class="text-align" style="cursor:pointer"><a ng-click="fnDisplayQuestions(value.quesList.quesListName,$index)"  >{{value.quesList.quesListName}}</a></p>
<uib-rating ng-model="rate" ng-if:"selectedQuestions" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="rating=value" ng-click="fnPutRating(rating)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating>
```

JS:

```
$scope.fnDisplayQuestions = function(qListName, index) { 
$scope.selectedQuestions=true;          
    $scope.indexQList = index;
    $scope.sQList = qListName;
if (parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('currentRound')) == 1) {
        getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQuestions(qListName).then(function(response) {
            $scope.aQuestions = response;
        });
    } else {
        getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQuesRoundBased(qListName).then(function(response) {
            $scope.aQuestions = response;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced so many problems for this scenario. I google out for different solution but none helped for me and finally i come across this solution. hope help someone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zUML.png)

=> Here we need to use Server side control binding.
=> We can do this easily using c# codebeheind file.

Step 1: Write parent ID for your outer div in .aspx page and make it as runat="server". and we will put our bootstrap tab div inside this div so that we can easily access child element of accordian class.

```
            <div class="panel-group accordion" runat="server" id="parenAccordian">                                   
                               <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a runat="server" href="Master.aspx?loadUC=One" data-target="#collapseOne" data-parent=".accordion"
                                                data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle tab_design" target="_self" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="spanOne" runat="server"></span>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTabOne" runat="server" Text="TabOne"></asp:Label>
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" runat="server" id="collapseOne">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div runat="server" id="divOne">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                               <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a runat="server" href="Master.aspx?loadUC=One" data-target="#collapseTwo" data-parent=".accordion"
                                                data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle tab_design" target="_self" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="spanTwo" runat="server"></span>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTabTwo" runat="server" Text="TabTwo"></asp:Label>
                                            </a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" runat="server" id="collapseTwo">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div runat="server" id="divTwo">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

        </div>
```

Step 2:Redirect to master page and pass query string as parameter to load clicked user control. whater is the querystring parameter according that we are going to take that querystring parameter to bind that usercontrol to that div only
e.g.: href="Master.aspx?loadUC=One"

Step 3: Write code in Page Load event

```
         string userControlID = ((System.Web.UI.Page)(sender)).ClientQueryString;
        var controlID = userControlID.Substring(userControlID.LastIndexOf('=') + 1);
        if (Request.QueryString["loadUC"] == controlID)
        {
            //get clicked control id
            HtmlGenericControl collapseDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)parenAccordian.FindControl("collapse" + controlID);
            collapseDiv.ID = "collapse" + controlID;
            collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("id", collapseDiv.ID);

            //load clicked user control and add bind to html div
            UserControl userControl = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ModuleEngineering/SystemConfiguration/" + "UC" + controlID + "System.ascx");
            userControl.ID = "test";
            string userControlDivID = "div";
            string modifiedControlDivID = userControlDivID.Insert(3, controlID + "Data");

            HtmlGenericControl userControlDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)parenAccordian.FindControl(modifiedControlDivID);
            userControlDiv.ID = modifiedControlDivID;
            userControlDiv.Controls.Add(userControl);

            //add remove collapse plus minus class on click
            HtmlGenericControl spanDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)parenAccordian.FindControl("span" + controlID);
            spanDiv.ID = "span" + spanDiv;
            spanDiv.Attributes.Add("id", spanDiv.ID);

            string newTabValue = Convert.ToString(Session["NewCollapseTabValue"]);
            if (Session["NewCollapseValue"] == null)
            {
                Session["NewCollapseValue"] = "panel-collapse collapse";
            }
            if (Request.QueryString["loadUC"] == newTabValue)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["loadUC"] == newTabValue)
                {
                    if (collapseDiv.Attributes["class"] != Convert.ToString(Session["NewCollapseValue"]))
                    {
                        collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-collapse collapse");
                        spanDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-plus");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-collapse collapse in");
                        spanDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-minus");
                    }
                }
                if (Request.QueryString["loadUC"] != newTabValue)
                {
                    if (collapseDiv.Attributes["class"] != Convert.ToString(Session["NewCollapseValue"]))
                    {
                        collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-collapse collapse in");
                        spanDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-minus");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-collapse collapse");
                        spanDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-plus");
                    }
                }
                Session["NewCollapseValue"] = collapseDiv.Attributes["class"];
            }
            if (Request.QueryString["loadUC"] != newTabValue)
            {
                if (collapseDiv.Attributes["class"] == Convert.ToString(Session["NewCollapseValue"]))
                {
                    if (collapseDiv.Attributes["class"] == Convert.ToString(Session["NewCollapseValue"]))
                    {
                        collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-collapse collapse in");
                        spanDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-minus");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-collapse collapse");
                        spanDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-plus");
                    }
                }
                else if (collapseDiv.Attributes["class"] != Convert.ToString(Session["NewCollapseValue"]))
                {
                    if (collapseDiv.Attributes["class"] != Convert.ToString(Session["NewCollapseValue"]))
                    {
                        collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-collapse collapse in");
                        spanDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-minus");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        collapseDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "panel-collapse collapse");
                        spanDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-plus");
                    }
                }
                Session["NewCollapseValue"] = collapseDiv.Attributes["class"];
            }
            Session["NewCollapseTabValue"] = controlID;
```

Step 4: If you click on Bootstarp tab button or Plus icon or Tab header it will add 'panel-collapse collapse in' class from codebehind and remove panel-collapse collapse class

Step 5: If you click again on Bootstarp tab button or minus icon or Tab header it will add 'panel-collapse collapse' class from codebehind and remove panel-collapse collapse-in class. and it will work as expected.

Step 5: And put your all Page binding method, dropdownlistbinding method, etc method's in Page_Init() mentod